# Libraries used by C# executables

Tags: executable, chroot, c#, libraries

I am having a problem when I try to run C# executables (compiled with mono C# compiler at 10.10 server) inside a chroot jail. In order to run the executable inside the jail I need to include the proper libraries. To do that I use ldd for C, C++, Pascal and other languages. Unfortunately this won't work for C# files ("ldd hello.exe" states that hello.exe is not a dynamic executable). Which libraries do C# executables use? Or do you know how ca I find them?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. =)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything that you're looking for is in :

```
/usr/lib/mono
```

It would be hard to only get parts of it, so you might try putting them all in the chroot.
For a list of the mono packages, do :

```
sudo aptitude search mono
```

Comment: i included the mono folder with all of it's contents inside the chroot but the problem still exists. :/